# Visual Studio Nuget review changes for solution copy text

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

**Edited:**
The dialog control does not allow copy the underlying review changes output text.

[image: a screen shot example]

Is there any other way, (e.g. is it possible to run NuGet for updating all the solution) and further get the similar output text?

Comment: Can you add a bit more details on what you're doing, which things you're trying to copy and possibly a screenshot? (you don't have enough points for images yet I think, just paste a imgur link and someone will fix up your post for you.

Comment: Has the same question with jessehouwing, could you edit your question with more detail info?

Comment: Behind the link is the screen shot of an example https://imagebin.ca/v/3dA3o0SpXfvG

Answer (score 0):

> Would there be any other way to get the text?

I do not think you can copy that text on that dialog.

When you upgrade nuget packages, a **modal window** displays which the dependencies of a chosen package. **The text  selection on the modal is disabled by default on that window**.

So we could not copy that text on that dialog.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Now I realized,  the question was understood a bit different I meant. Please excuse me about my English. I actually don't insist  copying the text right  from the dialog, it is quite obvious, it is not possible. Question should have been something like: "Is there any other way, (e.g. is it possible to run NuGet from command line) to get same or similar output as the text in the dialog?"

Comment: @MojmirRychly, As far as I know, we could not get those info firectly, if you want to get those info, you can refer to the method nuget package manager UI how to get those info. https://github.com/NuGetArchive/NuGet.PackageManagement/blob/e294559ce47eeba9e7ec6df56743f8abad9ff7ca/src/PackageManagement.UI/Xamls/PreviewWindow.xaml.cs

Comment: Thanks for your answer with the reference to the source code. I think that can help me.